# Не могу загрузить в Image WPF favicon

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, xaml

Написал тестовую программку, где динамически добавляется Label с названием сайта и Image которая с сайтов вставляет иконку, "Скриншот  рисунка прикреплю как примерно должно выглядеть". Label добавляется все нормально, но вот Image ни как не хочет добавлять "favicon.ico". В поисковике искал решение вопроса, пробовал по разному, но не получается.
[image: Пример программы]

пример моего кода:

```
private void Add_Ico()
    {
        try
        {
            using ( StreamReader st = File.OpenText( Global.syte ) )
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    string urls = st.ReadLine();
                    if(urls != null)
                    {
                        WebClient client = new WebClient();

                            string patch = urls + "/favicon.ico";
                            string save = @"";
                            client.DownloadFile( patch, save );
                               // BitmapImage bmp;
                               // using ( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( data ) )
                               // {
                                //    bmp = new BitmapImage();
                               //     ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                              //      bmp.BeginInit();
                               //     bmp.StreamSource = ms;
                               //     bmp.EndInit();

                                //}

                                //img = new Image();
                                // img.Source = ;
                                //img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                                //img.Height = 27;
                                //img.Width = 27;
                                //img.Margin = new Thickness( 27,15,0,0 );
                                //panel_syte.Children.Add( img );



                    }
                    else
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Файл пустой","Ошибка");

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В WPF всё прекрасно работает само, не надо ничего скачивать вручную.

```
<Image Source="http://google.com/favicon.ico">
```

Вот ваш список с иконками:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfFavicons.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Control.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Websites">
            <x:XData>
                <Websites xmlns="">
                    <Website Uri="http://google.com/" Favicon="http://google.com/favicon.ico"/>
                    <Website Uri="http://vk.com/" Favicon="http://vk.com/favicon.ico"/>
                    <Website Uri="http://mail.ru/" Favicon="http://mail.ru/favicon.ico"/>
                </Websites>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tplWebsite">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding XPath=@Favicon}" Margin="2 0" Width="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Uri}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Control.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Websites}, XPath=/Websites/Website}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tplWebsite}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую отпишусь)

Comment: Нет это не то, работает но не так. У меня программа запускается пустая изначально, я нажимаю на кнопку добавить сайт, появляется новое окно и в текстбокс вписываю сайт любой, нажимаю ОК. После этого добавляется Label с названием сайта и рядом должна появиться иконка этого сайта. Но увы не загружает с сайта, сразу в исключение кидает пишет "{"Не удалось найти часть пути \"D:\\Projects\\мои программы\\Syte_WPF\\Syte_WPF\\bin\\Debug\\www.google.ru\\favicon.ico\"."}".

Comment: У вас URI относительный (`www.google.ru/favicon.ico`), он интерпретируется как путь в файловой системе, а нужен URI абсолютный (`http://www.google.ru/favicon.ico`), чтобы не возникало неоднозначностей. Смотрите код из примера.

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек) Все исправил, заработало)) Спасибо!!!